# Don't allow cell to be moved to another section

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can I disable that the user can move cells to other sections? I don't want to show an alert each time ;)

Thanks :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Implement the targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath delegate method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath 
    toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section != sourceIndexPath.section)
    {
        //keep cell where it was...
        return sourceIndexPath;
    }

    //ok to move cell to proposed path...
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```